# Codemasters GRID and Driving Wheels

Tags: controllers, grid

I just recently got a hold of a G27 Racing wheel and been playing F1 2010 with it ever since.

Since F1 2010 is from Codemasters I assumed the older titles like DiRT 1+2 and GRID will also have awesome support for Racing Wheels and bought those.

After trying to play Grid now for almost 30 minutes I'm about to give up and go back to Keyboard driving since I can't seem to get the wheel to properly reset itself.

In F1 the wheel is centered like a real wheel of a car. If you let it go it will go back to it's center position and if you turn it only 10% your tires will only steer slightly.

In Grid there is absolutely no centering on the wheel (even if I turn force feedback on) and you can't really drive that way since it quite literally maps wheel movement to normal keys - so 10% on the wheel equals a pressed right key on a keyboard.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

GRID supports the Logitech Driving Force, Driving Force Pro and G25 wheel only.

But if you follow this recipe, GRID can work with G27 as well :

> By copying the G25 preset files, it is possible to make the game
>   work with the G27.
>
> In the .../GRID/ActionMap/ folder the G25 is actionMapPreset1.xml,
>   make a copy of that file, rename to "G25_actionMapPreset1.xml" for a
>   backup.
>
> Open the actionMapPreset1.xml file in a plain-text editor like Notepad
>   or Wordpad, change ALL instances of "G25" to "G27" (quotes here just
>   for clarity - don't add extra quotes in file).
>
> Save the file, save a copy as "G27_actionMapPreset1.xml" as a backup.
>   It's important the the file with the G27 edits remains named
>   actionMapPreset1.xml else it won't work.
>
> Run GRID, the G27 will be detected and displayed in the Controls menu.

Read more about G27 wheel support in this [thread](http://community.codemasters.com/forum/grid-tech-support-1020/402823-logitech-g27-wheel.html).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot .. I've been scouring the Codemasters forums for quite some time but 99% of the people where complaining about some driver issue where the wheel was not working at all... I'll try that once I am at home..