# Steering in drift session - Not able to take a big angle

Tags: grid

*May be related to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26328/codemasters-grid-and-driving-wheels).*

---

Yesterday, I started playing Grid after quite some time and focused on drift sessions.

The problem is the following : I couldn't help but think the drift cars feel weird.

I can drift pretty okay and get quite some points but I can't keep the car at a large angle for long even with the wheels completely turned. Also, drifting at low speed (<130kph) and changing drift direction (e.g. left turn to right turn) is rather tedious and not esthetic.

---

This is a question divided in several parts.

- Could my steering wheel (picture and name below) not be adapted and thus not translate properly my actions ? In fact, the front wheels don't seem to be able to reach a decent turning angle (for a drift car that is).
- If the steering wheel is not involved, could I be doing something wrong ? My drifting technique is self taught through trial and error (and basic physics understanding).
  *Reach a high speed (>80kph), use the brake pedal to put weight on the front axle while turning in the desired direction, counter-steer/accelerate and then play with the gas pedal/brake pedal/handbrake.*
- Finally, is it possible that the game does not allow to drift with a big angle ? If so, can something be done to improve the car behaviour ?

*Side-note : The AI seems to be able to drift without any problem at low speeds. Are the physics altered for them to have such nice trajectories ?*

---

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Should any additional info be needed, tell me.

---

My steering wheel : Logitech - Formula Force GP
[image]
*Image found there -> http://ratherget.com/*

Comment: What gear are you drifting in? I've noticed the cars seem to lose all power in 4th gear, and it feels reduced in 3rd, too. Try 2nd and see how that goes. Also, GRID is an arcade game so I don't know how well a wheel is going to work with it. Have you tried a controller to see if that fixes your problem?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion @CommandoAir.
I do drift in 2nd gear most of the time. A 'regular' controller doesn't seem to change anything so I'm guessing it's just the way the game is. I did try to change my technique a bit and I managed to get nicer drifts. Also, the car impacts a lot on the drift capability.

Comment: Do you run with stability control on or off? It's completely inaccurate in GRID and doesn't do what it actually does IRL. With it off, the car becomes more stable and way too understeery, so if you have it off, try turning it on. It makes the cars handle much more like they should (and all the AI have it on anyway).

Comment: Well that is interesting. I think I switched it off to actually have a more complete control of the car. I guess I'll try with and without the stability control and come back to give my feedback. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: No problem. I had the same thoughts at first. Naturally, when I start a racing game I always turn all assists off. So I was really confused when the AI could take corners far faster than I could. I was even more confused when I tried throwing the spyker C8 into a corner and couldn't get it to oversteer for anything.

Comment: After playing a bit yesterday, I noticed the help was switched off so I put it back on and it does allow a bigger angle. Drift-wise, I now pretty much have what I wanted. I'll post an answer in case someone needs it (not that I think anybody plays the game anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to CommandoAir, the source of the problem has been pinpointed.

In fact, switching the steering assist off will limit the maximum angle of you front wheels.
Other than that, all other driving help should not be enabled during drift sessions.

> **CommandoAir's enlighting comment**
>   Do you run with stability control on or off? It's completely inaccurate in GRID and doesn't do what it actually does IRL. With it off, the car becomes more stable and way too understeery, so if you have it off, try turning it on. It makes the cars handle much more like they should (and all the AI have it on anyway).